# How to display a lots of tabs in an webpage?

Tags: tabs

I'm working for an enterprise application for the screen to create invoice from Delivery Notes. Users can add a few or a lot of Delivery Notes in the invoice form. Each delivery note add a tab in the screen but if there are too many tabs, it creates a second line of tabs. This solution is not OK because it takes space in the screen and we prefer keep space for the table content (the table have much more columns and lines than the one in the wireframe)
[image: tabs on 2 lines]

I'm looking for other ideas for these case.

1 - Enable horizontal scrolling for tabs and guide users with a clickable arrow icon. The question is : Is it enough intuitive ?
[image: Scrolling on tabs]
2 - Add a dropdown list to select a tab not visible. The question is : how to display the tab selected with the dropdown ?
[image]

Any others ideas or any suggestions ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Looks like tabs are not the solution here. Are you stuck with the tab concept or are you open to taking a step back and try a different approach? In the case of the latter  a little more background info and context is needed to be able to give suitable ideas for your situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too many tabs - different ui layout?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/146986/too-many-tabs-different-ui-layout)

Comment: This same question is [repeated several times](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/9681/115107), use the search field to see all of them with their respective answers

Comment: Hi @jazZRo it's already developped, so yes we're blocked with the tabs solution.

Comment: Hello @Danielillo I'd already seen these posts  before I send mine. And unfortunately it's not answer my question, it's not the same context. The number of my tabs is dynamic (added by the users). In a lot of case, it would display well because the number of tabs is under 8. But sometimes, users need to add more tabs. :)

Comment: @Emilie not completely on-topic, but "it's already developed, we can't change it anymore" is a huge organisational red flag. I don't know where this is coming from, if that's something you decided on your own or if it's something decided higher up, but you need to be able to respond to changes in requirements / edge cases discovered after initial delivery.

Comment: Hi @Cubic I should be more precise, it's not blocked forever. But we need to deliver the first version quickly. So we can change it later in a future version if it's trully needed. The idea here is more to optimize the existant solution without break all that is already developped. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an inspiring watch, I found the same problematic on muliples tools : Excel, Teams, Monday and Google Sheets.

I prefer Google Sheets solution. If it can help anyone, here are some details :)

You can add a few or a lot of tabs like in our enterprise app, and to navigate throw tabs you can do it from different ways :

1. By clicking on the menu icon : it opens the list of all tabs
2. By simply scrolling over the tabs
3. By clicking on the arrows (on the right of the screen but a little cropped by the capture tool).
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to pitch this in the 'other ideas or suggestions' you request, to keep on topic!

I would go back to first principles. Can you reduce the volume of information by:

- removing columns?
- combining columns?
- moving repeated information from the columns to the heading (e.g. 'Price' and 'Total amount' repeat € every time)
- presenting different (smaller) tables depending on the user's task
- presenting less important information at a lower level

Could you replace the tabs with accordions and allow the user to view one or more at the same time?

Comment: Hi @Peter Thanks for your answer. For the table and the number of columns, of course we already thinking about the firt principles but our enterprise application is about a very specific activity sector and the users absolutely need all the columns. But this is OK. My problem is about the tabs, it's already developed so we can't change this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Vertical tabs along the left edge, like a secondary or tertiary navigation.